# JS ERROR: Error: Expected an object of type GCancellable for argument 'cancellable' but got type string

Tags: javascript, linux, gnome, gio, gjs

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Seed/Tutorial/simple_gio).
Basically, I want to create my custom function that creates a folder if it not exists.

```
var makeDir = (path) => {
    const file = Gio.file_new_for_path(path);

    if (file.query_exists(path)) {
        print(`Dir already exists ${path}`);
        return;
    }

    print(`My Path: ${path}`);

    // file.make_directory(path);
};
```

When I run this code I'm receiving an error:

```
Gjs-CRITICAL **: 17:35:17.161: JS ERROR: Error: Expected an object of type GCancellable for argument 'cancellable' but got type string
```

In the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-query-exists) I see that *GCancellable* is optional. So I have no idea why my code does not work. Haw can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C documentation, "optional" means something else than it usually does in JS: it means it's optional to pass a real pointer as that argument, and you may also pass `NULL`.

The error message is complaining about a string because `query_exists()` does not take a `path` string argument. Check the [JS documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gio20/gio.file#method-query_exists) for the list of arguments accepted in JS: you should call `file.query_exists(null)`.